# vagrant 'hostonlyif' create not working

Tags: vagrant, archlinux

I'm trying to do a vagrant up on a box, and I get the following error.

> INFO interface: error: There was an error executing the following command with VBoxManage:
>   ["hostonlyif", "create"]

When doing an INFO on the VAGRANT_LOG, I get

```
ERROR vagrant: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/driver/virtualbox_base.rb:278:in `block in execute'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:14:in `retryable'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/driver/virtualbox_base.rb:268:in `execute'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/driver/virtualbox_4_2.rb:61:in `create_host_only_network'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/action/vm/network.rb:276:in `create_hostonly_network'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/action/vm/network.rb:229:in `hostonly_adapter'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/action/vm/network.rb:36:in `block in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/action/vm/network.rb:31:in `each'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/action/vm/network.rb:31:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/action/vm/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.0.6/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
```

I've tried putting replacing the `'hostonly'` in the vagrantfile to `'hostonlyif'`, but that gives an error message saying that it should be set to `'hostonly'`.  How do I fix this erro?

The host machine is running archlinux, and I'm using the latest versions of vagrant and virtualbox.

Answer (score 24):

try with this:
sudo modprobe vboxnetadp

in my case it works

Comment: I had this issue but with an OS X host machine.
`sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart` fixed it for me.

Comment: @runamok That was it. Had to do this after upgrading to Mavericks from Mountain Lion.

Comment: What is the solution for Windows?

Answer (score 22):

I just recently updated to OS X 10.9 and had this problem with `vagrant up`.

If you're running VirtualBox version 4.2 or older, this should work:

`sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart`

However, if you're running a newer version of VirtualBox (4.3 or newer), try:

`sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist`

As noted in this question: [vagrant up failed, /dev/vboxnetctl: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149546/vagrant-up-failed-dev-vboxnetctl-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I think there's a typo in your Mac version but this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Worked for me after a Mavericks upgrade (10.8 to 10.9). thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced a similar problem, only there were no visible errors at all: the private network simply was never created. The solution was as dumb and simple as always in such cases:

```
$ pacman -S net-tools
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is experienced on Mac OSX Mavericks (10.9) and it's a permissions issue.

You can fix it by running:

`sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart`

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was also :

```
sudo modprobe vboxnetflt
```

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Load_the_VirtualBox_kernel_modules

Comment: that worked for me using Ubuntu 16.0.4, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the version of VirtualBox you are running in your question but for version 4.2.x the command listed by the previous answers:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

should fix your issue. If you are running 4.3.x though the equivalent to this command is:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
```

This will also restart the VirtualBox services and should fix your issue.

As a side note I have run into the issue where running that command will silently fail and cause VirtualBox to emit the same behavior you described. This is usually caused due to a VM still being active and can usually be resolved by suspending or destroying your vagrant instances or other VMs and rerunning the command.

Answer (score 1):

I found none of the above to work on El Captian, the following does:

```
sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue just restarting my MAC, and running again

```
vagrant up
```