# VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, development-environment, vagrant

I am running **vagrant** 1.4 and **virtual box** 4.3 on fedora 17 machine. When I do "vagrant up", I get this error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...                                                                            


[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...                                                                                                                
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...                                                                                                             
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant                                                                                                  
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.                                                                                                      

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]                                                                                                                                       

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Comment: you're running vagrant from fedora or that's your vagrant box os?

Comment: I have the same issue and running vagrant on OS X, is that the problem of virtual box?

Comment: @adi could you validate the right answer? Tks

Comment: You will probably have this issue when you update to MacOS Monterey an etc.  The accepted answer was no doubt the main problem but the MacOS upgrade may not copy your Security and Privacy settings, so I added that as well.  I do NOT know why this question was not simply moved instead of closed.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

I had the same problem today. The reason was that I had another VM running in VirtualBox.

**Solution:**

1. Open VirtualBox and shut down every VM running
2. Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy Then hit the "Allow" button to let Oracle (VirtualBox) load.
3. Restart VirtualBox

```sh
sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart
```

You should now be able to run `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload` and have your new host configured.

> As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50589920/2867976), recent versions of macOS can block VirtualBox.

**Solution:**

Go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy` Then hit the "Allow" button to let Oracle (VirtualBox) load.

(thanks to [@pazhyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3303055/anatolii-pazhyn), [@lsimonetti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321344/lsimonetti) & [@dave-beauchesne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6146535/dave-beauchesne) for clarifications)

Comment: Confirming this works on my Mac. Shutting down other VMs isn't sufficient, but restarting VB works.

Comment: Also worked for me, VirtualBox UI showed no VMs up, but restarting resolved the problem. Perhaps vagrant halt didn't finish successfully the last time.

Comment: This answer assumes, I guess, that VirtualBox is in your StartupItems. If it isn't, see @pazhyn's answer below, which seems to be more general & worked for me.

Comment: Does not work, virtualbox by default does not install at this location. I know mine is a default install and is not located in StartupItems. Please see @pazhyn answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @amateurbarista I've a default installation of VirtualBox and this work, as confirmed before by others, so your assertion is not correct. Although, I've also added the more common pattern, as this solution assumes VB is started with the system.

Comment: @totophe What about windows?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde On Windows, you should just restart the virtual machines from VirtualBox and maybe restart VirtualBox itself.

Comment: would running parallels also be an issue causing this error?

Comment: @GeorgeD. Not to my knowledge

Comment: Had to do this and then click "Allow" in System preferences as mentioned by some other answers. Without this, the "Allow" did not appear even.

Comment: Confirmed on: - Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101), - Vagrant 2.2.9, Virtualbox v6.0.22

Comment: Big Sur, system pref -> security & privacy -> general -> unlock to make changes -> advanced -> approve and reboot

Comment: I never got the "Approve" button in Security & Privacy settings, despite following all advice. An extra restart solved it. Restart after each fix that you try, to save some headache.

Comment: On OSX 13 Ventura, go to  System Settings > Privacy & Security > Profiles > Open "Oracle VirtualBox VM" > Install... I think

Comment: What's the fix for Ventura 13.0.1? I'm running the Developer Preview for M1/M2 if that matters. If I go to Privacy and Security > Profiles, the existing profile expired in 1940. Could this be the issue and how do I update that if so?

Answer (score 64):

For Mac OS X 10.9.3 and Vagrant 1.6.3 and VirtualBox 4.3.6 this problem was fixed with restarting the VirtualBox

```
sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart
```

Comment: Works for me, VirtualBox 4.3.18, OS X 10.9.3. Thanks!

Comment: For any one having the same question on:
Mac OS 10.13 + vagrant 2.2.0 + VirtualBox 5.2.20
this worked perfectly for me.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked for me. OS X with VirtualBox 6.0 and Vagrant 2.2.7

Comment: Yes. Destorying the previous VM didn't do it for me.

Comment: This did not work for me - apparently the various shutdowns didn't work It says things like "Unloading VBoxUSB.kext", but then later it says "Error: VBoxUSB.kext is already loaded".

Answer (score 56):

> **TL;DR** MacOS is probably blocking VirtualBox. Go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy` Then hit the "Allow".

Solution:
Go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy` Then hit the "Allow" button to let Oracle (VirtualBox) load.

**MacOS by default can block kexts from loading. You must click the "allow" button before executing the VirtualBoxStartup.sh script.**

Then run: 
`sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart` like the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21363356/3321344).

([This article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2459/_index.html) provides more clarity to MacOS kernel extension loading)

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Comment: ```MacOS by default can block kexts from loading. You must click the "allow" button before executing the VirtualBoxStartup.sh script.```

That was the issue for me ! Thanks!

Comment: On macOS BigSur (11.0.1) I had to update Virtualbox to the latest version before getting the prompt on `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General` to "Allow". A system restart was also required after allowing.

Answer (score 17):

This issue appears to be fixed by installing the [latest version of Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: My case is Vagrant 1.7.4+Virtualbox 5.0+Windows 10 build 10240. Version 5.01 fix the issue.

Comment: I get this error also with Virtualbox 7.0, but reinstalling might cause virtualbox to restart, which is resolves the issue.

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue after upgrading to OS X El Captian.  Upgrading to the latest version of VB solved the issue for me.  Virtual box will give you the latest link if you go to the virtualbox menu at the top of your screen and clicking check for updates.

Answer (score 10):

Got the error in Mac after the update to Mojave. Probably you have an older version of virtual box.

**Update to a recent version of virtualbox. (5.2 at the time of wrting this post)**

**Edit:** adding @lsimonetti's comment.

In addition to that upgrade to Virtualbox 5.2, you need Vagrant >= 2.0.1

Comment: In addition to that upgrade to Virtualbox 5.2, you need Vagrant >= 2.0.1 https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/v2.1.5/CHANGELOG.md#201-november-2-2017

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Linux, simply run: `sudo vboxreload`

Comment: vboxreload does not exist. Neither vbox

Answer (score 7):

I'm running **Oracle VM Virtualbox** on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**.

The solution that worked was to reinstall virtualbox as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/912276):

`sudo apt remove virtualbox virtualbox-5.0 virtualbox-4.*`

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

I couldn't find my VirtualBox installation folder, as such could not issue the command:

`$sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart`

Comment: My local env just stopped responding.  Could not get vagrant up.  remove and installed vbox fixed whatever was the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem upgrading to OSX Monterey.

Solution:

1. Install VirtualBox Extension ([download](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.28/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.28.vbox-extpack))
2. Accept VirtualBox Security & Privacy/Privacy/Input Monitoring

[image]

VirtualBox can also have and lose permissions for Accessibility, check that as well

[image]

Comment: Thanks. More about how to solve it [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12557#issuecomment-954124748).

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem on Monterey.

Answer (score 6):

I had to reinstall Virtual Box on my machine.

Here's the downloads page: [Downloads Page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Then `vagrant up` worked for me after.

Answer (score 6):

If after performing what is said by @totophe and on macOS it still doesn't work, just restart your mac. Then open the terminal and `vagrant up`.

This usually happens after each macOS update.

Comment: Yep, just restarting my Mac fixed it, thanks! (from 11.5.1 to 11.5.2)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was able to solve this issue by reinstalling virtual box. I was trying to use laravel's homestead and was having this error. Reinstalling helps creating the directories that are needed for virtual box again. Took me an hour to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

Worked great for me on Mac. This normally happens when I shut down my computer without running

```
$vagrant suspend
```

Comment: On Ubuntu: sudo systemctl restart virtualbox

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Debian 8 (Jessie), Vagrant 1.6.5 and Virtual Box 4.3.x with the same problem.

For me it got fixed executing:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried multiple solutions but the below sequence works for me.

Virtual Box: 5.2.34
Vagrant: 2.2.5
Mac OSX: 10.14.6

**First Allow access to oracle inc:**

> Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy Then hit the "Allow" button to let Oracle (VirtualBox) load.

Then restart VBox by this command:

```
sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
```

Now try Vagrant up again.

Comment: That Allow access thing won't be shown after the update, only after install I guess. But the command does the job on Big Sur 11.5 and 11.6. One note - after that command I also had to do the restart.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had the same problem after upgrading to mac os Big Sur

Linus solution worked for me

1. Grant permission to VirtualBox under System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General (this request is new to macOS High Sierra)
2. Open Terminal and run: sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47652517/6146535

Answer (score 2):

I am using ubuntu 14.04.  I have genymotion installed on virtualbox.  Every time I start genymotion I had no problem, but suddenly one time it said unable to load virtualbox engine and it didn't open.  I went through the log file and found out it could not create a new host only network because it has already created all possible host only networks.  And the problem is that it cannot allocate memory for a new network.

Fix: go to your virtual box File --> Preferences --> Network

Click the host-only tab and just delete some of the host-only networks so that you will get some memory freed and next time, a new network can be created easily.

Deletion fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was using Virtual Box on windows and had exactly same issue. Your hint of checking preferences of network helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to do the following to solve this error for me:

**totophe's** answer in combination with (re)**installing** the latest VM-version (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (Thanks to jacobappleton & user1718159)

Steps:

- First (re)install latest VirtualBox;
- Run `sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart` in terminal (not sure if this is needed in order to get the system preferences show up the allow/disallow option);
- Allow in Security & Privacy
- Restart your machine
- Run `sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart` again.

Ready to run `vagrant up` again.

Comment: The main answer is correct, HOWEVER .... this post does say to reinstall VirtualBox which is what helped Apple recognize and re-approve the security preferences for me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by installing VirtualBox 4.2 instead of 4.3. I think the latest version of vagrant and VB 4.3 are incompatible on a fedora system.

Answer (score 1):

- CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
- VirtualBox-5.0

I came across this tread while searching Google for...
 **VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter**

I was using VirtualBox-5.0 to test some virtual machines created with Vagrant and setting private networks in my Vagrantfile
  **web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.2"**

When evoking the command **$ vagrant up** I would get the above mentioned error along with **/dev/vboxnetcrl does not exist**.

It seems that my version of VirtualBox did not have the proper kernel module compiled for my version of Linux and the device, /dev/vboxnetcrl, does not get created.

Since I wanted to test virtual machine and not troubleshoot VirtualBox, my work around (not a solution) was to:

```
 # yum remove VirtualBox-5.0
 # yum install VirtualBox-4.3
```

After that I was able to create the virtual machines with specified host-adapters. And of course, under VirtualBox-4.3, /dev/vboxnetcrl was there.

Now on to testing my VMs. And when I have time, I'll see if I can get it working under VirtualBox 5.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are on **Linux**:

```
sudo service virtualbox restart
```

Comment: service not found :( although virtual box is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Pro
VirtualBox 5.2.12

In my case I had to edit the Host Only Ethernet Adapter in the VirtualBox GUI. Click Global Tools -> Host Network Manager -> Select the ethernet adapter, then click Properties. Mine was set to configure automatically, and the IP address it was trying to use was different than what I was trying to use with drupal-vm and vagrant. I just had to change that to manual and correct the IP address. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just now and it was solved by simply reinstalling to the latest version of VirtualBox.

For those on Mac OS High Sierra - the installation might fail at first but you need to go to System Preferences > Security & Policy and click on the "Allow" button to allow Oracle installing the software.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Mojave, this solution worked:

```
sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue on mac.

I did the following 
Go to: 
Launcher->Virtualbox

Click the icon to open Virtualbox

Start Virtualbox with the button that pops up once Virtualbox starts. Wait till the terminal window gives you the prompt,

docker@boot2docker

Then try to open docker. Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you have allow Oracle from `system preference` and the error still persist. It is highly possible you have not started VirtualBox. Ensure it is running and run `vagrant up` again.

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked for me by following  Given link.

https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/drupal-vm-failed-create-host-only-adapter/

- Tried on : 06 Mar, 2021
- Mac OS = 11.2.2 (20D80)
- Oracle Virtual Box = Version 6.1.18 r142142 (Qt5.6.3)

```
~ ➤ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox Manager1

Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(Manager1) Copying /Users/speedoo/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/speedoo/.docker/machine/machines/Manager1/boot2docker.iso...
(Manager1) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(Manager1) Creating SSH key...
(Manager1) Starting the VM...
(Manager1) Check network to re-create if needed...
(Manager1) Found a new host-only adapter: "vboxnet0"
(Manager1) Waiting for an IP...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with boot2docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: docker-machine env Manager1
~ ➤
~ ➤

~ ➤ docker-machine ls

NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER      ERRORS

Manager1   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v19.03.12

~ ➤
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped me on Opensuse 42.1 is to install VirtualBox and Vagrant from the official RPMs instead of from Opensuse repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on Windows 8.1, VirtualBox 5.1.18 and Vagrant 1.9.3.

Deleting the VirtualBox Hosts-only Ethernet Adapter from VirtualBox Preferences (Network --> Hosts-only networks) fixed this for me, and `vagrant up` could continue and start the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while following a tutorial on setting up Laravel Homestead for Windows 10. The tutorial provides an example IP address `192.168.10.10` to use for the server. The problem with their example IP is that **if you already have a VirtualBox Host-Only Adapter set up, the IP you use for your vagrant server must have the same first three parts of the IP address of your current adapter**.

You can check what your current Virtualbox Host-Only Adapter IP address is by running `ipconfig` (windows) `ifconfig` (mac/linux) and looking for VirtualBox Host-Only Adapter's IPv4 address. `192.168.56.1` was mine. Usually if the host IP is `192.168.56.1` then the guest IP will be `192.168.56.101` so instead of using the example IP I used `192.168.56.102`. **Any IP that is within `192.168.56.*` that is not already taken should work**.

After this `homestead up` worked perfectly for me.

> **TL;DR - If your current VirtualBox Host-Only Adapter IP is 192.168.56.1, make your Vagrant server IP 192.168.56.102.**

Answer (score 0):

If you use macOS High Sierra or upper version you can find the bash script at the location:

```
sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
```

So If you got this kind of error:

> /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) system policy prevents loading; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).

You can solve it via `System Preferences > Security & Privacy` section and `Allow` the VirtualBox.

Comment: Where do I set the allow?

Answer (score 0):

My solution

> System Preferences -> System Security Privacy -> Allow oracle.xxxx; then reinstalling the virtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

I want to mention that.

> Open VirtualBox and shut down every VM running.

The shut down should be power off.

And if your virtualbox has been added in the Path in linux (Mine is Ubuntu). You can just use command:
`virtualbox restart`

Answer (score 0):

I came here, working with kitchen-CI and having problems with vagrant.
After (re-)moving the "~/.kitchen"-directory the `kitchen converge` was successfull again

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can be fixed by provisioning the box on vagrant up

```
vagrant up --provision
```

Comment: The first vagrant up normally provisions itself... And running the provision again can mess everything up. Provisioning is often not written to run twice (not idempotent), so it will execute things again. That is always very dangerous unless you have written everything so well that it can run multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Arch. Here is how I solved it.

I needed all the following packages:

```
➜  ~ pacman -Ss virtualbox | grep installed
extra/linux-zen 5.12.14.zen1-1 [installed]
community/virtualbox 6.1.22-3 [installed]
community/virtualbox-ext-vnc 6.1.22-3 [installed]
community/virtualbox-guest-iso 6.1.22-1 [installed]
community/virtualbox-guest-utils 6.1.22-3 [installed]
community/virtualbox-host-dkms 6.1.22-3 [installed]
community/virtualbox-sdk 6.1.22-3 [installed]
chaotic-aur/linux-tkg-muqss 5.12.15-178 [installed]
chaotic-aur/virtualbox-ext-oracle 6.1.22-1 [installed]
chaotic-aur/virtualbox-meta 2-1 [installed]
```

My AMD motherboard (Gigabyte X570 AORUS Master) had AMD Secure Virtual Machine (SVM) set to 'Disabled' by default. I changed it to 'Enabled' in the BIOS.

Rebooting and running:

```
vagrant up
```

Finally worked without any issues. Just be sure to obviously have a properly configured Vagrantfile.

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

Make sure you have the following files under System32:

```
vboxnetadp.sys

vboxnetflt.sys
```

You can download them from here:

http://www.sysfilesdownload.com/V/VBoxNetFltsys.html

http://www.sysfilesdownload.com/U/VBoxNetAdp.sys.html