# How run android on genymotion

Tags: android, linux, genymotion

After installing genymotion I try to start this app. But genymotion says - On your computer not launched Virtual Machine...

I open Virtual Box and try to creating new Linux, Ubuntu(64) machine. I start this machine and fetched more and more errors from virtual box (i not understand these errors).

How to launch genymotion, without these all problems. Light way?

```
мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 1 
мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] Output command: "0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp" 
мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] failed to create host only interface 
мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] "Fail to load vboxmanage plugin from /opt/genymotion/plugins/" 
мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] VM Engine failed to load 
мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to launch the Genymotion VM from Genymotion Programm Interface (like [this one](http://www.technotalkative.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Genymotion-AVD-manager.png)). Not from VirtualBox.

Android Studio will **recognize the virtual device as a real one**, not a VM.

Comment: My genymotion not started

`мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] Output command: "0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] failed to create host only interface 
мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] VM Engine failed to load 
мая 6 20:28:09 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted.`

Comment: @AlexanderDemidov see this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069908/vboxmanage-error-failed-to-create-the-host-only-adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can install Genymotion plugin on Android Studio.

[on this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vlbj.png)

When you restart the IDE a Genymotion icon will appears in your toolbar
Start a virtual machine and Android Studio will recognize as a real device

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely follow the Getting started section of the Genymotion User Guide. It is very exhaustive and explains everything you need to know about the product.

Here is the link: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#getting-started