# Vagrant fails to communicate with VirtualBox: Inappropriate ioctl for devic

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-15.10

I have a **Vagrant** VM setup to run with **VirtualBox**. Currently after trying to start it by using the command `vagrant up`, I get the following error in my console:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Tried reinstalling **VirtualBox** with same results. My operating system is **Ubuntu Gnome 15.10**. Did some research but got similar results with a solution only for **OSX**.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069908/vboxmanage-error-failed-to-create-the-host-only-adapter)