# VBoxManage error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) -VBoxManageControlVM.cpp

Tags: chef-infra, virtual-machine, virtualbox, development-environment

I ran into Virtualbox shutting down a VM while trying to run kitchen test using Vagrant as the driver.

I restarted  Virtualbox as mentioned in "[VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069908/vboxmanage-error-failed-to-create-the-host-only-adapter)".

How can I move further in resolving this?

- VirtualBox Version: 5.0.14r105127
- kitchen version: 1.6.0
- Vagrant 1.7.3
- chef-client version: 12.8.1

This is the error:

```
Message: Failed to complete #destroy action: [Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of vagrant destroy -f ----
STDOUT: ==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
STDERR: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
Command: ["controlvm", "3fa0e654-df44-4050-809f-2d1474b74a8f", "poweroff"]
Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to power off machine
VBoxManage: error: The VM session was aborted
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface ISession
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleControlVM(HandlerArg*)" at line 234 of file VBoxManageControlVM.cpp
---- End output of vagrant destroy -f ----
Ran vagrant destroy -f returned 1]
```

Comment: What OS is the host?

Comment: @coderanger I am on OS X el Capitan (10.11.4) and trying to launch ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I receive this error when trying to run `docker-create` with the `virtualbox` driver. In my case, a VPN connection was causing the problem. Disconnecting from VPN, then running docker-create fixed my problem. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

After spending way too many hours working through cryptic VirtualBox errors, I've decided the fastest way for me is not just to restart virtualbox, but to also clean up the virtualbox temp folder (`"~/VirtualBox\ VMs"` or similar).

99% of the time, this helps overcome the intermittent error and allows me to focus on the actual problem I was working on.

For me, only if the error does persist after all this, it is worth looking into it further.