# `VBoxManage` error on VirtualBox when running Vagrant after MacOS Monteray update

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vvv-wordpress

Now, I've seen a few questions regarding my issue on various Stack websites and also on `GitHub`. However, after trying everything they have recommended, my environment still doesn't work, which is why I'm opening a new question.

Prior upgrading to `Monteray`, `vagrant up` would run successfully. But, ever since the upgrade, I see the following error message on:

```html
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

**Details**:

`Vagrant` version `2.2.19`

`VirtualBox` version `6.1`

**What I've tried:**

1. Complete uninstalls and re-installs of `Vagrant` and `VirtualBox`. Permissions have also be granted in `Security and Privacy`.
2. I've tried to force `gui` rather than `headless` by setting `v.gui = true` in my `Vagrantfile` as suggested [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12557#issuecomment-954124748) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1683747/vagrant-virtualbox-not-working-after-upgrading-to-monterey).
3. I've tried installing older versions of `VirtualBox` to see if it solved the issue.
4. Tried installing the `VirtualBox` extension, restarted my Mac and ran `vagrant up`, but no change. [See accepted answer here for my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069908/vboxmanage-error-failed-to-create-the-host-only-adapter).

I've ran out of avenues to try. Wondering if anyone had any alternative approaches as I'm stumped.

Comment: exact issue, exact attempts

Comment: updating virtualbox fixed the issue, apparently this happens whenever mac os releases a major update, virtualbox needs a bit of time to patch, current virtualbox version 6.1.30 (download it manually, auto update doesn't work for some reason)

Good luck

Comment: Hi @UXLabs - Glad to hear it's working for you. I've downloaded the latest VirtualBox version (6.1.3 for MacOS) and when running `vagrant up`, I now see no errors. However, none of my sites load. When going to `http://vvv.test/`, it doesn't load either. Is it the same for you?

Comment: Hello @Freddy just saw this, here everything went back to normal as soon as downloaded the update, i hope you worked it out, it sounds like /etc/hosts issue

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you update VirtualBox and don't restart your machine. VirtualBox uses kernel extensions, and in v7+ it uses another feature for network adapters. These requires a hard reboot.

So restart your Mac, and if that does not work, reinstall VirtualBox then restart it again. If that fails, completely remove VirtualBox, restart, install the newest version, restart, *then* try to provision.

---

BTW I'm the VVV project lead, usually when we see these issues we fix them, this isn't something you should need to fix yourself. But if you use stack overflow to report bugs we don't see it. **Either raise a GitHub issue or ask in the VVV slack.** We could have gotten to this in minutes/hours rather than *years*.

https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/new/choose
https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/docs/en-US/slack/