# vvv.test not loading (nor any of my sites) when running vagrant up

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, virtualbox

Ever since I've upgraded my `Mac` to `Monteray`, I've been having issues with `Vagrant`.

Initially, I use to see a `vBoxManage` error on `terminal` when running `vagrant up`. I posted a question on this on SO previously, [see here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69890710/vboxmanage-error-on-virtualbox-when-running-vagrant-after-macos-monteray-updat).

Today, I uninstalled `VirtualBox` again (removed `VirtualBox VMs` folder and moved application to trash) and reinstalled `VirtualBox 6.1.3` for OS X hosts` ([link here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)).

I then ran `vagrant up` on `terminal` and it successfully compiled:

[image]

After seeing the famous green teddy, I tried going to `vvv.test` but, the page doesn't load. I've tried accessing URLs of sites that have been `provisioned` before, but they too do not load.

I've also ran `vagrant up --debug`, and nothing concerning was seen.

My `Vagrant` version is `2.2.19`

Unsure what steps to take next?

**Edit:**

Steps taken:

1. Have ran `vagrant up --provision` to provision sites in `config.yml` file (`config.yml` file can be seen below)
2. Have tried to access `website-dev.test`, page doesn't load
3. Have tried to access `vvv.test`, page doesn't load
4. Have ran `vagrant reload --provision` and repeated steps 2 and 3, but same results
5. Have ran `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up` and repeated steps 2 and 3, but same results

I don't believe there's an issue in my `config.yml` file, as before `Monteray` update, everything was working fine (and I've made no changes to my `yml` file since). But, to cover all scenario's, here is my `config.yml` file:

```html
sites:

  website-dev:
    skip_provisioning: false
    description: ""
    hosts:
      - website-dev.test
    custom:
      wpconfig_constants:
        WP_DEBUG: true
        WP_DEBUG_LOG: true
        WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER: true


  wordpress-trunk:
    skip_provisioning: true 
    description: "An svn based WP Core trunk dev setup, useful for contributor days, Trac tickets, patches"
    repo: https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/custom-site-template-develop.git
    hosts:
      - trunk.wordpress.test

  wordpress-meta-environment:
    skip_provisioning: true 
    description: "An environment useful for contributions to the WordPress meta team."
    repo: https://github.com/WordPress/meta-environment.git
    hosts:
      - wp-meta.test
    custom:
      provision_site:
        "buddypressorg.test": true
        "jobs.wordpressnet.test": true
        "wordcamp.test": true
        "wordpressorg.test": true
        "wordpresstv.test": true

utilities:
  core: 
    - tls-ca 
    - phpmyadmin

vm_config:
  memory: 1600
  cores: 2

general:
  db_backup: true
  db_restore: true
  db_share_type: false


vagrant-plugins:
  disksize: 10GB
```

In regards to `vagrant ssh`, I'm unsure on what steps I would need to take to get `vvv.test` to start working again here, can't see anything on the [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/ssh) for this also?

Comment: Did you try to ssh into your VM? Once the virtual machine has booted you can ssh into by simply running 'vagrant ssh'. Also we need to add the site to the sites section of the .yaml file. So, try to add 'http://vvv.test' in your yaml file and then reload the virtual machine, using the command 'vagrant reload --provision'.

Comment: Hi @Tinxuanna - I've updated my question to reply to your above questions :)

Comment: What comes to my mind, is to go to '/etc/hosts ' file and add the ip of the website-dev.test site (if it isn't already added). Also, visit [macOS Monterey and VB issues](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12557), if it has something to help you with your issue. Maybe, reporting the issue there is gonna help you.

Comment: Have you tried Docker? I was having multiple issues with Vagrant on Windows, I switched to Docker and to me it seems more intuitive than Vagrant/Ansible combo.

Comment: Have you tried this to enable logging? https://superuser.com/questions/804214/how-to-enable-vagrants-verbose-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to guidance from @Tinxuanna, I've managed to solve the issue (finally!).

For anyone else having similar issues, here's what I did:

1. Access the `/etc/hosts` folder
2. Find file called `hosts` and open it in a text editor.
3. Remove the IP addresses related to `vagrant` (I kept a backup of the original file just in case)
4. After saving `hosts` file the IP addresses removed, I ran `vagrant up --provision`
5. I then ran `vagrant up`
6. Then accessed `vvv.test`
7. You're done!

Answer (score 0):

After trying the solutions provided by others, I determined that the problem on my machine was a wrong ip range in Vagrantfile. To solve this:

1. Edit Vagrantfile
2. Change IP `defaults['private_network_ip'] = '192.168.56.4'` to different range
3. Save it and run `vagrant up --provision`

If [Freddy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70368690) doesn't work, then give this a try.