# Issue running homestead after upgrading macos

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm running Virtualbox 7.0
I'm running vagrant 2.3.3
I'm running mac big sur

When I run vagrant up it creates a new vm, but I'm getting an error.

This is the error.

homestead: ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.

This is a fresh install of all software. Could someone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why am I getting a negative for something that I don't know? If I'm asking obviously I'm tried measures to correct the issue, but can't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do also have that problem. However I see that Laravel's documentation is talking about Virtualbox 6.1.x, maybe this will work for you? I still have some weird issues even with that version of VB, but who knows in your case :/

---

**[EDIT]** I just tried another install, with Vagrant 2.3.3 and VirtualBox 7.0.4. My first `vagrant up` failed, because of "nfs" type used (which I'm using out of habit but I guess it's not really mandatory) and it seemed to work after that.

I would advise you to fully uninstall Vagrant and VirtualBox, and try again with latest version.

PS : I'm also on Mac Big Sur.

PPS : You made me wonder "why not try with VB 7.0.x ?"

---

**[EDIT 2]** I actually managed to make everything work with VirtualVox 6. I actually was stuck on some weird error message stating something like

```
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

And it looks [like this guy had the answer for Mac users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21363356/6083234) :

1. Open VirtualBox and shut down every VM running
2. Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy Then hit the "Allow" button to let Oracle (VirtualBox) load.
3. Restart VirtualBox

It all worked like a charm after that.

Comment: Thanks for answering @ZyDucksLover. I'll try it and let you know the result.

Comment: ZyDucksLover have you ever gotten this erro?  

homestead: ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed.

Comment: Your initial post is talking about "logs above", have you any error? This looks like an SSH error, which I had initially as well.

What I did prior to everything I mentioned above is that I uninstalled Vagrant : https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/installation/uninstallation, uninstalled VirtualBox. And then I installed the latest version of Vagrant and VirtualBox 6.1.40. Keep your "Security & Privacy" panel opened and when you see "Oracle (VirtualBox)" blocked, unblock it. I also removed my SSH keys and generated new ones : `ssh-keygen -t rsa` (default options all the way)

Comment: Worked like a charge. Thanks ZyDucksLover you're great.