# vagrant up failed, /dev/vboxnetctl: no such file or directory in MAC Big sur M1 chip

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, macos-big-sur

While trying to do `vagrant up` getting error in terminal

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

I am using mac BigSur M1 chip.

Some solution I try

1. Try to do reinstall virtualbox
2. [vagrant up failed, /dev/vboxnetctl: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149546/vagrant-up-failed-dev-vboxnetctl-no-such-file-or-directory) but there is not any grant permission option in BigSur.

Any help would be appreciated.