# apt-get install build-essential not working on vagrant through provision

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have the following in my Vagrantfile. It install vim, but it does not install nodejs, git etc. How to change it so that it run apt-get install build-essential git-core python-software-properties nodejs? Or should I do this with puppet file?

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: './provision.sh'  
  config.vm.network "public_network"
end
```

provision.sh

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential git-core python-software-properties nodejs
apt-get install vim -y
```

====

### UPDATE: This is the outputs of vagrant up.

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'ubuntu32'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
2) en0: Ethernet
3) p2p0
What interface should the network bridge to? 1
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
[default] Machine booted and ready!
[default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
cause things such as shared folders to not work properly. If you see
shared folder errors, please update the guest additions within the
virtual machine and reload your VM.

Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
VirtualBox Version: 4.3
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] Running provisioner: shell...
[default] Running: /var/folders/y0/dzf6yf9n5r1bsl3p94lmv2fr0000gp/T/vagrant-shell20131108-47487-13ypot
stdin: is not a tty
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [92.5 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [2,494 B]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [29.6 kB]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1,804 B]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [354 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4,620 B]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [88.4 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,640 B]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [74 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [934 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [159 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,299 B]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en [1,253 B]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en [53.8 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources [5,019 kB]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources [155 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [1,274 kB]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages [8,431 B]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [4,796 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages [121 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex [3,706 B]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex [2,676 B]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex [2,596 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex [2,922 B]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [424 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [7,006 B]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [99.2 kB]
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [8,354 B]
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [723 kB]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [11.4 kB]
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [225 kB]
Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.2 kB]
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [3,564 B]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex [2,605 B]
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex [2,461 B]
Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [2,850 B]
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources [4,233 B]
Get:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources [36.1 kB]
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources [5,311 B]
Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages [2,838 B]
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:55 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages [36.7 kB]
Get:56 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [5,178 B]
Get:57 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex [70 B]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]
Get:61 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en [726 kB]
Get:62 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en [93.4 kB]
Get:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en [2,395 B]
Get:64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en [3,341 kB]
Get:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en [317 kB]
Get:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en [8,136 B]
Get:67 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,637 B]
Get:68 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [129 kB]
Get:69 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en [2,072 B]
Get:70 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en [4,610 B]
Get:71 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en [14 B]
Get:72 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en [26.9 kB]
Fetched 19.6 MB in 1min 21s (242 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.6 git git-man libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libc-ares2 libdpkg-perl
  liberror-perl libev4 libicu48 libstdc++6-4.6-dev libv8-3.7.12.22 make patch
  python-pycurl unattended-upgrades
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-4.6-multilib gcc-4.6-doc libstdc++6-4.6-dbg
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-arch git-cvs git-svn
  git-email git-gui gitk gitweb libstdc++6-4.6-doc make-doc diffutils-doc
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-dbg bsd-mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.6 git git-core git-man
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libc-ares2 libdpkg-perl liberror-perl libev4 libicu48 libstdc++6-4.6-dev
  libv8-3.7.12.22 make nodejs patch python-pycurl python-software-properties
  unattended-upgrades
0 upgraded, 24 newly installed, 0 to remove and 155 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 72.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Abort.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 libpython2.7 python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-runtime
  vim-tiny
Suggested packages:
  gpm python2.7-doc binfmt-support ctags vim-doc vim-scripts indent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 libpython2.7 vim vim-runtime
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-tiny
4 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 151 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 27.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libgpm2 i386 1.20.4-4 [16.9 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7 i386 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4 [2,647 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7-minimal i386 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4 [1,690 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main vim-tiny i386 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 [380 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main vim-common i386 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 [85.8 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libpython2.7 i386 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4 [1,148 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main vim-runtime all 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 [6,277 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main vim i386 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 [979 kB]
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
Fetched 13.2 MB in 49s (270 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libgpm2.
(Reading database ... 29361 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libgpm2 (from .../libgpm2_1.20.4-4_i386.deb) ...
Preparing to replace python2.7 2.7.3-0ubuntu3 (using .../python2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement python2.7 ...
Preparing to replace python2.7-minimal 2.7.3-0ubuntu3 (using .../python2.7-minimal_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement python2.7-minimal ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4) ...
(Reading database ... 29364 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace vim-tiny 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2 (using .../vim-tiny_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement vim-tiny ...
Preparing to replace vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2 (using .../vim-common_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement vim-common ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7.
Unpacking libpython2.7 (from .../libpython2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vim-runtime.
Unpacking vim-runtime (from .../vim-runtime_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_all.deb) ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/help.txt to /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/help.txt.vim-tiny by vim-runtime'
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/tags to /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/tags.vim-tiny by vim-runtime'
Selecting previously unselected package vim.
Unpacking vim (from .../vim_2%3a7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libgpm2 (1.20.4-4) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4) ...
Setting up vim-common (2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up vim-tiny (2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libpython2.7 (2.7.3-0ubuntu3.4) ...
Setting up vim-runtime (2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing /usr/share/vim/addons/doc
Setting up vim (2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/vim (vim) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/vimdiff (vimdiff) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/rvim (rvim) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/rview (rview) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/vi (vi) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/view (view) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/ex (ex) in auto mode.
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

Comment: I'd guess that you need a -y on the apt-get install for the failing packages but I'm not certain. What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. But when I vagrant ssh and check the version, it suggests to install.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, can you destroy your old VM with vagrant destroy; make a new one from vagrant up and then copy and paste the output from vagrant up into your question please? I just don't have enough information to go off here.

Answer (score 3):

I am running Vagrant 1.3.5 and VirtualBox 4.3.2 r90405 on Mac OSX Mavericks. I downgrade VirtualBox to 4.2.18 (I will change to 4.2.0) and installed vagrant-vbguest

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

Then I run this command.

```
$sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

Found at [vagrant 'hostonlyif' create not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404777/vagrant-hostonlyif-create-not-working)

I added -y to apt-get

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install build-essential git-core python-software-properties nodejs
apt-get -y install vim
```

Then it installed all.